# With what quality or sense does Simon Peter ask Jesus to leave him in Luke 5:8?

Tags: jesus, peter

> But when Simon Peter saw it, he fell down at Jesus' knees, saying, "**Go away from me**, Lord, for I am a sinful man!"
> Luke 5:8 NET@

Some references to "ἐξέρχομαι ἀπό" Matt. 12:43; 17:18; 24:27; Lk. 4:35; 5:8; 8:29, 46; 9:5; 11:24; Acts 16:18; 19:12; Phil. 4:15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter saw a phenomenon, the interpretation of which needed to be achieved by answering the following questions: could Jesus have known that there were many fishes? Humanly - no!

But even had He known it by divine inspiration, it is not a knowledge of a static thing, but of a caravan of fishes who change their position all the time in a matter of seconds; so, Peter was initially hesitant and started to procrastinate by complaining that he had tried all night; now, had Peter not procrastinated he would have caught those fishes, but even as he procrastinated, he achieved the same. Now this is possible only if Jesus Himself made fishes not to swim anywhere, but to swim into Peter’s nets the moment he would put them into the water. And He did that authoritatively and confidently, without prayers.

Now, could angels force fishes to do so? No. Prophets and saints? - No. Is it a prerogative of only God? Yes. Only and exclusively. Thus it obtains that Jesus holds the same sovereign authority over the created nature as only God holds; therefore, in virtue of holding such a sovereign authority, so as to govern powers of nature at will, Jesus is God.

Peter being awed for that matter, asked Him to leave him, for he felt himself utterly unworthy.

Comment: Excellent answer.  +1.

Comment: @Dottard Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a larger portion of the passage.

Luke 5

> 4 When he had finished speaking, he said to Simon, “Put out into deep
> water, and let down the nets for a catch.”
>
> 5 Simon answered, “Master, we’ve worked hard all night and haven’t
> caught anything. But because you say so, I will let down the nets.”
>
> 6 When they had done so, they caught such a large number of fish that
> their nets began to break. 7 So they signaled their partners in the
> other boat to come and help them, and they came and filled both boats
> so full that they began to sink.
>
> 8 When Simon Peter saw this, he fell at Jesus’ knees and said, “Go
> away from me, Lord; I am a sinful man!” 9 For he and all his
> companions were astonished at the catch of fish they had taken, 10 and
> so were James and John, the sons of Zebedee, Simon’s partners.
>
> Then Jesus said to Simon, “Don’t be afraid; from now on you will fish
> for people.” 11 So they pulled their boats up on shore, left
> everything and followed him.

When the fishing instructions of Jesus were followed it resulting in a huge catch of fish. This caused Simon to realize that Jesus was a representative of God. Peter recognized that he was sinful and unworthy of Jesus presence. This recognition of unworthiness caused Simon to ask Jesus to leave.
Simon was unworthy of being in the presence of Jesus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An angel? A divine spirit?